# How to configure default push on a per-remote basis?

Tags: git, web-deployment, git-remote

I have a website that I deploy with git. It is stored (for source control purposes, not deployment) on the 'origin' remote on branch 'production' (also my local branch). So I can maintain my source code there with a simple:

```
$ git push
```

(i.e. I have the default push set up to push 'production' to 'origin/production').

I have a test server and a live server, configured as git remotes, and I currently deploy with:

```
$ git push test production:master

$ git push live production:master
```

I.e. those remotes are using their master branch - they have no 'production' branch, or indeed any concept or knowledge of this branch name.

I'm wondering if there's a way to set up my .git/config such that I can simply do this:

```
$ git push test
```

and

```
$ git push live
```

and it will push my local production branch to the remotes' master branches, as before.

This may sound like I'm being lazy (and I probably am), but I'm also hoping that the answer to this will help me understand a bit more about how remotes and branches are configured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure it with the `push` setting in `.git/config`:

```
 [remote "test"]
      push = production:master

 [remote "live"]
      push = production:master
```

The `push` setting is the <refspec> used by `git push` when none is given, e.g. `git push test`.

(For the `push` setting above to take effect you have to have the 'production' branch currently checked out)